# PHP Serialize($array) without dumping array info a:1:{i:0;s:4.... and so on

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

Is there anything that i print the string without the array information?
(Without this:  **a:1:{i:0;s:4011:" ";}**  )?
The whole array must be in single variable and printed. Foreach doesn't help, neither print(array[0]).

Comment: So you want to `echo $array[0]`?

Comment: No, i have few elements in this array (everytime different count).

Comment: so `foreach($array as $element) echo $element[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which will give you less verbose string representation:

```
<?php
$a = array('a', 'bb' => 'ccc');
echo json_encode($a);

// outputs {"0":"a","bb":"ccc"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

echo json_encode($array);

This will print a json encoded string.

For you to decode it you can use

json_decode(json encoded string);

You can see docs of php about json encode and json decode